# Views get node which created entity?

Tags: 7, views, commerce, entities

I am using commerce, which has products as entities. I have each product as a main node (which has title, URL, body, and other basic stuff) then I have a field which references products (price, SKU, product title, image, etc). And then I have a field called recommended products which references products. So a pretty standard commerce setup, nothing overly fancy.

I want to get all of the reference products (so I can show a you may also like product 1, product 2, etc) AND the node which created the product (so I can show a URL to that main product page (thats it, I just want a URL)). And this is where I am running into the issue, I have zero problem getting the product. But I cannot seem tog et the node which created the product.

Is there anyway using views to get the node which created an entity? I have tried everything I can think of.

Comment: So is the nid of the associated node a property of the product entity?

Comment: Nope I'm not sure how best to associate the entity with a node.